# intellij kotlin dependency failed to find premain-class

Tags: maven, kotlin, intellij-idea

I recently wanted to learn kotlin coroutines and add them to my maven project. I added this to the pom.xml:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jetbrains.kotlinx</groupId>
    <artifactId>kotlinx-coroutines-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.4.3</version>
</dependency>
```

Sounds easy enough but now when I want to start my project I get the following errors:

```
"C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-11.0.10-hotspot\bin\java.exe"
Failed to find Premain-Class manifest attribute in C:\Users\j\.m2\repository\org\jetbrains\kotlinx\kotlinx-coroutines-core\1.4.3\kotlinx-coroutines-core-1.4.3.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument

Process finished with exit code 1
```

That's pretty much all I did in Intellij. Is there anything I missed which is required to be able to use coroutines?

It works, when I compile and run the project with Maven as follows:

```
mvn -pl client -am clean install package
cd client/target
java -jar client-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

**/edit1:**
Seems like it happens only when debugging. Running the app normally works as expected.

**/edit2:**
Finally I found a ticket which seems to cover this problem: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTIJ-5659

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me is enabling this config from Intellij:

```
Preferences | Build, Execution, Deployment | Debugger | Data Views | Kotlin | Disable coroutine agent
```

Just check this box and it will work.